# Unexpected character in input サーバーでクローンしたらエラー

Tags: php, laravel, cron

```
PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  ' ' (ASCII=2) state=0 in /opt/php-5.4.16/bin/php on line 2849 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T_STRING) in /opt/php-5.4.16/bin/php on line 2849
```

X-Serverのクローン機能で下記のコマンドを実行すると上記のエラーでました。

```
php /usr/bin/php5.4 /home/XXX/XXX.com/public_html/test/project/artisan schedule:run
```

言語はPHPで、Laravel5.6を使用しています。
PHPのバージョンは7.2.17を使用していますが、クローンのコマンド欄で`php --version`と実行すると、なぜか5.4(CLI)でした。
最初は7.2(CLI)のパスでコマンドを実行していたのですが、ディレクトリが見つからないみたいでだめでした。5.4にすると上記のエラーがでました。
どういう意味のエラーなのかさえわからないので対応に困っています。

わかる方、対処法、またはこの記事に書いてあるなど教えていただければ助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 問題を解決した方法
`php /usr/bin/php5.4 /home/XXX/XXX.com/public_html/test/project/artisan schedule:run`このコマンドを`/usr/bin/php7.2 /home/eXXX/XXX.com/public_html/test/project/artisan schedule:run`に変更したら走りました。

Comment: 詳細は回答をご覧ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://readouble.com/laravel/5.6/ja/installation.html
laravel 5.6はPHP7.1.3以上がサーバ要件として求められています。

https://www.xserver.ne.jp/manual/man_program_soft.php
XSERVERはコマンドパスを公開していますので、こちらから対象のコマンドパスを選んでCronに設定してください。

```
/usr/bin/php7.2 /home/XXX/XXX.com/public_html/test/project/artisan schedule:run
```

※ご利用のサーバ情報などはXサーバー側のパネル等から確認できると思います。

＝＝＝追記＝＝＝＝

```
php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

とつなげて書く必要は有りません。

```
/usr/bin/php7.2
```

とこれだけでコマンドが実行できます。

解説
phpコマンドに限らずあらゆるコマンドは基本的に/usr/bin/以下に実体が存在し、
XサーバーはPHPのバージョンごとのコマンドはそれぞれ実体を直接利用してくださいといっています。
なのでphpコマンドを使わず直接/usr/bin以下の対象のファイルをコマンドとして実行可能です。

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございます。

`php /usr/bin/php7.2 /home/XXX/XXX.net/public_html/test/project/artisan schedule:run`

こちらのコマンドで実行すると下記のエラーがかえって来ました。

`PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  ' ' (ASCII=15) state=0 in /opt/php-7.2.27/bin/php on line 3108 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '  ' (T_STRING) in /opt/php-7.2.27/bin/php on line 3108`

エラーが変わったのでうれしいです。
自分でも調べるのですが、このエラーから予測できる対応方法などあれば教えていただけるとたすかります！

Comment: 回答に追記しました。

Comment: すみません、私のコマンドが悪かったようです。。。  
`/usr/bin/php7.2 /home/XXX/XXX.net/public_html/test/project/artisan schedule:run`  
上記のコマンドで実行したら走りました！  
どうやら、頭の`php `がいらなかったようですね。。。
ありがとうございました。